# wordpress v2 REST API - structured response (JSON) without HTML

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a open source light weight CMS with good REST API support. The use case us to have a central content repository for mobile apps, web site, support site and such. Multi-site support via API will be useful as well to organize conteant better,

From what I've read, Wordpress V2 REST API provides JSON response with HTML embedded. I need the content alone without any markup. Is this possible in wordpress? Do you guys recommend any other open source CMS that runs on Linux?

Comment: Wordpress can run as well on linux as on windows or any other machine where php and mysql database are set up. [About REST API](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/)

Comment: Thanks! I know Wordpress can run well. What I'm looking for a content available via REST API without HTML markup

Comment: Did you even check link I posted in comment?

Comment: Yes I did, look at the example JSON at the end of this document - https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/get/sites/%24site/posts/%24post_ID/, The content has HTML tags in them. What i'm looking for is to retrieve only the content without the markup

Comment: @Chida did you find any solution so far?